# An application of divergence theorem？

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

In a textbook about elliptic equations, I see the following formula:
$$\int_{ B_{\rho}  }\Delta u (x)dx=\rho^{d-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\left( \rho^{1-d}\int_{\partial B_ \rho}  u\ d S\right), $$
where $B_\rho$ is a ball with radius $\rho$ and centered at origin in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
The author said the formula is derived by the divergence theorem, which as I known is written by
$$\int_\Omega  \nabla \cdot f dx= \int_{\partial \Omega } f \cdot n dS, f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d . $$
And he stated the following calculation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{B_\rho}\Delta u dx=&\int_{\partial B_\rho}\frac{\partial u }{\partial n }dS\\
=& \rho^{d-1}\int_{|w|=1}\frac{\partial u }{\partial \rho }(\rho w)dw\\
=& \rho^{d-1}\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho }\left( \rho^{1-d}\int_{\partial B_{\rho}  } u dS \right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I am curious about the second and third step:

1. How does the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial n } $ change to $\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho }$, where the former is a vector and the latter is just a scalar.
2. How does the derivate $\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} $ work on $\int_{ \partial B_\rho }u dS $?

Any detailed explanation will be appreciated :)

Comment: You seem to have a typo in "How does the derivative $\frac\partial{\partial n}$ change to $\frac\partial{\partial n}$"? And what do you mean by the second question? (As it's currently written, my answer would be: It works like it always does, it differentiates with respect to $\rho$.)

Comment: @joriki Yes, the typo is corrected. And I'd like to change the statement of the second question: why does the last equality hold? can you give a detailed calculation?

Comment: Where does a derivative change from $\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}$?

Comment: @joriki sorry, it should be "$\partial/\partial n$ change to $\partial/\partial \rho$", which is in the second equality.